# Error with own Tensorflow Lite Object detection model on RPI

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite

I trained my own Object Detection Model and wanted to use it. The model worked before freezing and compiling it and I thought quite a while what the problem could be ,but my mind pretty much thinks everythin should be fine. I have the directory with my model and labelmap right beside a directory with the original coco ssd v1 320 model. The coco model works completly fine but I absolutly don´t get the problem with my own model. When starting it I get a error which would be translated to English something like a Segmentation failure or straight forward a storage error. I have also compiled it to the format of my edge Tpu then starting it I get the error:TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float32' has no len(). I used my own and diferent types of code from the Internet. The following is basically the code from Edje Electronics, but you get the point.
Hier geht es zu meinem code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-KE2RVNYUrITiHJ5f8y2dRlXYVE7QHci/view?usp=sharing,
Ohh sorry, normaly it was just one time black but that also didn´t worked and I thought of id 0 but didn`t worked either
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MdjukruyZ4kBVQ2BKPVuZomWxNXXom8U/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SGLaH8vqhFK0pTZFARiUT6G32-3K8_uX/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wAZjHQiJKJYaC-31NOF42u6stTPZxoSV/view?usp=sharing

````
#
# Author: Evan Juras
# Date: 10/27/19
# Description: 
# This program uses a TensorFlow Lite model to perform object detection on a live webcam
# feed. It draws boxes and scores around the objects of interest in each frame from the
# webcam. To improve FPS, the webcam object runs in a separate thread from the main program.
# This script will work with either a Picamera or regular USB webcam.
#
# This code is based off the TensorFlow Lite image classification example at:
# https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/python/label_image.py
#
# I added my own method of drawing boxes and labels using OpenCV.

# Import packages
import os
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread
import importlib.util


print(1)
# Define VideoStream class to handle streaming of video from webcam in separate processing thread
# Source - Adrian Rosebrock, PyImageSearch: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/28/increasing-raspberry-pi-fps-with-python-and-opencv/
class VideoStream:
   """Camera object that controls video streaming from the Picamera"""
   def __init__(self,resolution=(640,480),framerate=30):
       # Initialize the PiCamera and the camera image stream
       `enter code here`self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
       ret = self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'))
       ret = self.stream.set(3,resolution[0])
       ret = self.stream.set(4,resolution[1])``
           
       # Read first frame from the stream
       (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

   # Variable to control when the camera is stopped
       self.stopped = False

   def start(self):
   # Start the thread that reads frames from the video stream
       Thread(target=self.update,args=()).start()
       return self

   def update(self):
       # Keep looping indefinitely until the thread is stopped
       while True:
           # If the camera is stopped, stop the thread
           if self.stopped:
               # Close camera resources
               self.stream.release()
               return

           # Otherwise, grab the next frame from the stream
           (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

   def read(self):
   # Return the most recent frame
       return self.frame

   def stop(self):
   # Indicate that the camera and thread should be stopped
       self.stopped = True

# Define and parse input arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--modeldir', help='Folder the .tflite file is located in',
                   required=True)
parser.add_argument('--graph', help='Name of the .tflite file, if different than detect.tflite',
                   default='detect.tflite')
parser.add_argument('--labels', help='Name of the labelmap file, if different than labelmap.txt',
                   default='labelmap.txt')
parser.add_argument('--threshold', help='Minimum confidence threshold for displaying detected objects',
                   default=0.5)
parser.add_argument('--resolution', help='Desired webcam resolution in WxH. If the webcam does not support the resolution entered, errors may occur.',
                   default='1280x720')
parser.add_argument('--edgetpu', help='Use Coral Edge TPU Accelerator to speed up detection',
                   action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

MODEL_NAME = args.modeldir
GRAPH_NAME = args.graph
LABELMAP_NAME = args.labels
min_conf_threshold = float(args.threshold)
resW, resH = args.resolution.split('x')
imW, imH = int(resW), int(resH)
use_TPU = args.edgetpu

print(2)
# Import TensorFlow libraries
# If tflite_runtime is installed, import interpreter from tflite_runtime, else import from regular tensorflow
# If using Coral Edge TPU, import the load_delegate library
pkg = importlib.util.find_spec('tflite_runtime')
if pkg:
   from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter
   if use_TPU:
       from tflite_runtime.interpreter import load_delegate
else:
   from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import Interpreter
   if use_TPU:
       from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import load_delegate

print(3)
# If using Edge TPU, assign filename for Edge TPU model
if use_TPU:
   # If user has specified the name of the .tflite file, use that name, otherwise use default 'edgetpu.tflite'
   if (GRAPH_NAME == 'detect.tflite'):
       GRAPH_NAME = 'edgetpu.tflite'       

# Get path to current working directory
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to .tflite file, which contains the model that is used for object detection
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,GRAPH_NAME)
   # CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,GRAPH_NAME)


# os.path.join(home/pi/tflite1/ball_model/detect.tflite)
   # CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,GRAPH_NAME)

# Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,LABELMAP_NAME)

print(4)
# Load the label map
with open(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'r') as f:
   labels = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

# Have to do a weird fix for label map if using the COCO "starter model" from
# https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview
# First label is '???', which has to be removed.
if labels[0] == '???':
   del(labels[0])
if labels[0] == 'black':
   del(labels[0])

print(5)
# Load the Tensorflow Lite model.
# If using Edge TPU, use special load_delegate argument
if use_TPU:
   interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT,
                             experimental_delegates=[load_delegate('libedgetpu.so.1.0')])
   print(PATH_TO_CKPT)
else:
   interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT)
   
print(6)

interpreter.allocate_tensors()

print(7)
# Get model details
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]
width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]

floating_model = (input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32)

input_mean = 127.5
input_std = 127.5

# Initialize frame rate calculation
frame_rate_calc = 1
freq = cv2.getTickFrequency()

print(8)
# Initialize video stream
videostream = VideoStream(resolution=(imW,imH),framerate=30).start()
time.sleep(1)

#Fenster Beweglicher
cv2.namedWindow('Object detector', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
#for frame1 in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",use_video_port=True):
print(9)

while True:

   # Start timer (for calculating frame rate)
   t1 = cv2.getTickCount()

   # Grab frame from video stream
   frame1 = videostream.read()

   # Acquire frame and resize to expected shape [1xHxWx3]
   frame = frame1.copy()
   frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame_rgb, (width, height))
   input_data = np.expand_dims(frame_resized, axis=0)

   # Normalize pixel values if using a floating model (i.e. if model is non-quantized)
   if floating_model:
       input_data = (np.float32(input_data) - input_mean) / input_std

   # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
   interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'],input_data)
   interpreter.invoke()

   # Retrieve detection results
   boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])[0] # Bounding box coordinates of detected objects
   classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0] # Class index of detected objects
   scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])[0] # Confidence of detected objects
   #num = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[3]['index'])[0]  # Total number of detected objects (inaccurate and not needed)
   print(10)
   # Loop over all detections and draw detection box if confidence is above minimum threshold
   for i in range(len(scores)):
       if ((scores[i] > min_conf_threshold) and (scores[i] <= 1.0)):

    
           # Get bounding box coordinates and draw box
           # Interpreter can return coordinates that are outside of image dimensions, need to force them to be within image using max() and min()
           ymin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][0] * imH)))
           xmin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][1] * imW)))
           ymax = int(min(imH,(boxes[i][2] * imH)))
           xmax = int(min(imW,(boxes[i][3] * imW)))
           
           cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin,ymin), (xmax,ymax), (10, 255, 0), 2)

           # Draw label
           object_name = labels[int(classes[i])] # Look up object name from "labels" array using class index
           label = '%s: %d%%' % (object_name, int(scores[i]*100)) # Example: 'person: 72%'
           labelSize, baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, 2) # Get font size
           label_ymin = max(ymin, labelSize[1] + 10) # Make sure not to draw label too close to top of window
           cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, label_ymin-labelSize[1]-10), (xmin+labelSize[0], label_ymin+baseLine-10), (255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED) # Draw white box to put label text in
           cv2.putText(frame, label, (xmin, label_ymin-7), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 0), 2) # Draw label text
           
           #Die Mitte bestimmen
           xcenter = xmin + (int(round((xmax - xmin) / 2)))
           ycenter = ymin + (int(round((xmax - xmin) / 2)))
           cv2.circle(frame, (xcenter, ycenter), 5, (0,0,255), thickness=-1)
           
           #erstmal anzeigen
           print('Object ' + str(i) + ': ' + object_name + ' at (' +str(xcenter) + ', ' + str(ycenter) + ')')

         
   
   print(11)
   
   # Draw framerate in corner of frame
   cv2.putText(frame,'FPS: {0:.2f}'.format(frame_rate_calc),(30,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(255,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

   # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
   cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

   # Calculate framerate
   t2 = cv2.getTickCount()
   time1 = (t2-t1)/freq
   frame_rate_calc= 1/time1

   # Press 'q' to quit
   if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
       break

# Clean up
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
videostream.stop()  ```


 [1]: https://
````

Answer (score 0):

It is because model output details has changed to solve this make little changes .
boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0]

classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[3]['index'])[0]

scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])[0]

thanks